# change Bluetooth from master to slave using bluez library

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

**Description:**
 I have a small in-house device with bluetooth capabilities.
 At the moment , other devices connect to that box.

**Requirement:**
 Now we have to make it slave so that it get connected with other devices. I am wondering how to do it ? I don't need source code or anything just your views.

**Additional Information:**
The application uses Bluez libraires to send command to firmware/hardware and we extensively use HCItool.

**Operating system :**
 Fedora.

I am also wondering , do I need to change chipset? From google it doesnt look like we need to change it.

Any help will be beneficial to us.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the command line, the way to achieve what you want is to use the #hcitool. However, you must first be connected. Try this sequence:

```
hcitool cc AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF            #Connect to the device
hcitool con                             #To make sure you are in a connection
hcitool sr AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF <role>     #switch master/slave role
```

If the output of "hcitool con" indicates that you are not in a connection, try the following sequence:

```
hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
hciconfig hci0 piscan 
sdptool add SP
rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 1 &
hcitool con
hcitool sr AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF <role>
```

The above code is specifically for the serial profile, but it has worked for me on several occasions when 'hcitool cc' failed.

If you want to see the source code for this, open the tools/hcitool.c source file in the bluez directory and navigate to the function:

```
static void cmd_sr(int dev_id, int argc, char **argv)
```

This is the function that fires up the sequence for switching between master and slave role. Following this function you can see what exactly happens through the bluez stack.

I hope this helps.

Comment: hi Yosuf, I have given command something like  "hcitool sr 74:F0:6D:E1:35:02 slave"  where bd-addr I got from hcitool dev  and everytime i get  not connected result . why is that so?

Comment: THanks a lot mate for  quick help

Comment: It seems that you must be in connection to switch between roles with the device you are connected to. I have edited my question to take this into consideration. Please note that the MAC Address AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF is that of the connected device, not of the local device. In other words, the MAC Address should be the output of the 'hcitool scan' command and NOT the 'hcitool con' command.

Comment: Yosuif, so basically once you are connected with remote device you can THEN  make our local device as slave or master?

Comment: I alos need helpp related to SCO Loopback ? I have searched a lot but couldnt able to find answer for my query . Wondering if I raise new question if you know about it?

Comment: Yes if you are connected you should be able to switch between roles. I haven't worked with SCO Loopback so I don't think I can help, but raise the question anyway.

Comment: Thanks Mate. Your help is indeed very beneficial to me.